# What is the Python equivalent of Ruby's Base64.urlsafe_encode64(Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(STRING))

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruby

I am trying to port parts of a ruby project to python and cannot figure out the equivalent to `Base64.urlsafe_encode64(Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(STRING))` Closest I have gotten is `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.sha256(STRING.encode('utf-8')).digest())` however giving the input of `StackOverflow` it returns: `b'HFqE4xhK0TPtcmK7rNQMl3bsQRnD-sNum5_K9vY1G98='` for Python and `MWM1YTg0ZTMxODRhZDEzM2VkNzI2MmJiYWNkNDBjOTc3NmVjNDExOWMzZmFjMzZlOWI5ZmNhZjZmNjM1MWJkZg==` in Ruby.

### Full Python & Ruby Code:

---

#### Ruby

```rb
require "base64"
require "digest"

string= "StackOverflow"
output= Base64.urlsafe_encode64(Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(string))

puts output
```

#### Python

```py
import hashlib
import base64

string = str("StackOverflow")
output = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.sha256(string.encode('utf-8')).digest())

print(str(output))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original Python code, you used `digest` instead of `hexdigest` which will give different results, as it's not the same thing. Keep in mind that converting code to different languages can be very difficult, as you need to understand both languages well enough to compare the code. Try and dissect the code piece by piece, splitting lines and printing each strings output / giving output at each stage to check what is happening.

Jamming everything into one line can be messy and you can easily overlook different factors which could play a major role in bug fixing.

You should write your code "spaced-out" at first, and in production you can change the code to be a singular line, although it's not very readable with long code.

---

What you are looking for is:

```
string = str("StackOverflow")
output = hashlib.sha256(code_verifier.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
output = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(code_challenge.encode('utf-8'))

print(str(output.decode('utf-8')))
```

It gives the same result, as if you are using `Base64.urlsafe_encode64(Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(string))` in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `hexdigest` method instead of `digest` on the hash in Python to get the same output as in your Ruby example (since you use the `hexdigest` function there).

Also note that the `hexdigest` method returns a string instead of bytes, so you'll need to encode the result again (with `.encode("utf-8")`).

Here's a full example:

```py
import hashlib
import base64

string = "StackOverflow"
output = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.sha256(string.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest().encode("utf-8"))

print(str(output))
```